# New to Android App / Java development, working through some abnormalities

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As the title says I am just getting started writing an Android smartphone application and it is the first time I have written in Java as well. I do have some experience with **C/C++/Swift/iOS** app development.

I have been watching tutorials and I have managed to get some basic things working with buttons but there are a few abnormalities I would like to change. For starters, it seems to only allow me to declare button variables and utilise them within the scope of the `onCreate()` method of my `main activity` in my code shown below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final boolean[] connect_btn_pressed = {false};

        final ImageButton btn_up = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_up);
        final ImageButton btn_connect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
        final TextView ble_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bt_message);

        btn_up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        btn_connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(connect_btn_pressed[0] == false){
                    ble_status.setText("Connecting...");
                    btn_connect.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_x1_bt_on);
                    btn_up.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    connect_btn_pressed[0] = true;
                }
                else {
                    ble_status.setText("Cancelled");
                    btn_connect.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_x1_bt_off);
                    btn_up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    connect_btn_pressed[0] = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If I try to move everything outside the `onCreate()` method, I cannot use the `btn_up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` call as it has some issue with the `View.INVISIBLE` argument.

The keyword `final` was placed for me, and I am not sure why that was necessary.

Lastly, my `boolean` variable was also turned into an `array` with a single element as soon as I tried to refer to it within the `onClick()` method. I will just let that slide if it is truly necessary but it still bugs me that I cannot just use it a simple boolean element.

So how can I move these lines of code outside the scope of `onCreate()`? I will want to refer to these buttons in the `onPause()` method but they won't be accessible in this current state.

Why do my variables need to be declared `final`? And do I really need to declare my `boolean` flag as an `array`?

Edit:

Now I have my code set up like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean connect_btn_pressed = false;

    ImageButton btn_up = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_up);
    ImageButton btn_down = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_down);
    ImageButton btn_right = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_right);
    ImageButton btn_left = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_left);
    ImageButton btn_connect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
    TextView ble_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bt_message);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btn_down.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btn_right.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btn_left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        btn_connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!connect_btn_pressed){
                    ble_status.setText(R.string.bt_statusmessage_connecting);
                    btn_connect.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_x1_bt_on);
                    btn_up.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_down.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    connect_btn_pressed = true;
                }
                else {
                    ble_status.setText(R.string.bt_statusmessage_cancelled);
                    btn_connect.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_x1_bt_off);
                    btn_up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_down.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_right.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    connect_btn_pressed = false;
                }
            }
        });

    }




    /*btn_left.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });*/

    /* Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        //
    }

}
```

It builds and runs but now as soon as the activity is started my app crashes. This is my stack trace:

```
09/21 14:00:23: Launching app
Cold swapped changes.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.rcbot/com.rcbot.Splash" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 13828 on device samsung-sm_g930p-91daafa6
E/Zygote: v2
W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0012
E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.rcbot 
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10214
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.rcbot-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.rcbot rsrc of package com.rcbot
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.rcbot-2/lib/arm64
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.rcbot, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.rcbot-2/lib/arm64
D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.rcbot
I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.rcbot, Feature store :{}
I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/data/com.rcbot/files/instant-run/right/resources.ap_ / 1.0 running in com.rcbot rsrc of package com.rcbot
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
D/RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
D/ContextRelationManager: ContextRelationManager() : FEATURE_ENABLED=true
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.rcbot-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.rcbot rsrc of package com.rcbot
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.rcbot.Splash isFragment :false
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{705cd69 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : f3dae48, Ic65b418ec7
          Build Date                       : 04/08/16
          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
          Local Branch                     : 
          Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.HB.1.1.1.C1.06.00.00.165.137
          Remote Branch                    : NONE
          Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f64a3a188
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.rcbot.Splash
I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.rcbot.Splash
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.rcbot
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@da565f2 time:125966383
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.rcbot, PID: 13828
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.rcbot/com.rcbot.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3093)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:116)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:29)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:199)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                      at com.rcbot.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:24)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1095)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3083)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

When I revert the changes the app runs just fine.

SOLVED:

The reason it was crashing was because I was attempting to set the declared variables with findViewById before it was ready. I fixed it by keeping the declarations above `onCreate()` and then moving the assignments to those variables inside it.

Comment: boolean connect_btn_pressed = Boolean.FALSE; Moreover, you need to get your basics clear about Java.

Comment: Hm, it was working with just 'bool x = false' but I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some changes like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
boolean[] connect_btn_pressed ;
ImageButton btn_up,btn_connect ;
TextView ble_status;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connect_btn_pressed = {false};

        btn_up = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_up);
        btn_connect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
        ble_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bt_message);

        btn_up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        btn_connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(connect_btn_pressed[0] == false){
                    ble_status.setText("Connecting...");
                    btn_connect.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_x1_bt_on);
                    btn_up.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    connect_btn_pressed[0] = true;
                }
                else {
                    ble_status.setText("Cancelled");
                    btn_connect.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_x1_bt_off);
                    btn_up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    connect_btn_pressed[0] = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, corrected:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean connect_btn_pressed = false;

private ImageButton btn_up;
private ImageButton btn_connect;
private TextView ble_status;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    connect_btn_pressed = false;

    btn_up = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_up);
    btn_connect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
    ble_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bt_message);

    btn_up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    btn_connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (connect_btn_pressed == false) {
                ble_status.setText("Connecting...");
                btn_connect.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_x1_bt_on);
                btn_up.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                connect_btn_pressed = true;
            } else {
                ble_status.setText("Cancelled");
                btn_connect.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_x1_bt_off);
                btn_up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                connect_btn_pressed = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

1) final, in your approach, was necessary due to scope. Was not a class variable, its scope was the method, so inside the OnClickListener was not "viewable".

2) By taking your variables in the new scope, I had no problems with the View argument. Im not sure why you needed to do it.

3) Now your variables can be used in onPause() method, the explanation is the same: they were out of scope.

Comment: Hm, well it builds and runs but now as soon as the activity starts my app crashes.

Comment: Well, look into the stacktrace to learn where the error is. Usually it points you straight to the exact line where it is.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the family marco!

try declaring the `reference` variable outside the `onCreate()` method! that is you should not declare it local to `onCreate()` method!

only then you'll be able to access the `btn_up.setVisiblity()`. if you do so the implicitly occuring of `final` will be eliminated too.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the ImageButton btn_up, for example, outside onCreate, and initialize it inside the onCreate, this way you can access it in onPause:

```
ImageButton btn_up;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btn_up = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_up);
btn_up.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

About the boolean variable - you declared it as an array when you added []... you can do it the same way:

Outside onCreate:
`boolean connect_btn_pressed;` // Default value is false

and then in onClick:

```
if(!connect_btn_pressed){ //if connect_btn_pressed is false

}
```